# Partitioning of Data Frame in Pyspark using Custom Partitioner

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Looking for some info on using custom partitioner in Pyspark. I have a  dataframe holding country data for various countries. So if I do repartition  on country column, it will distribute my data into n partitions and keeping  similar country data to specific partitions. This is creating a skew partition data when I see using `glom()` method.

Some countries like USA and CHN has huge amount of data in particular dataframe. I want to repartition my dataframe such that if the countries are  USA and CHN then it will further split into some 10 partitions else keep the  partitions same for other countries like IND, THA, AUS etc.  Can we extend partitioner class in Pyspark code.

I have read this in below link that we can extend scala partitioner class in scala Spark application and can modify the partitioner class to use custom logic to repartition our data on base of requirements. Like the one I have.. please help to achieve this solution in Pyspark.. See the link below [What is an efficient way to partition by column but maintain a fixed partition count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670369/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-partition-by-column-but-maintain-a-fixed-partition-c/38680666)

---

**I am using Spark version 2.3.0.2 and below is my Dataframe structure:**

```
datadf= spark.sql("""
    SELECT    
        ID_NUMBER ,SENDER_NAME ,SENDER_ADDRESS ,REGION_CODE ,COUNTRY_CODE
    from udb.sometable
""");
```

The incoming data has data for six countries, like `AUS`, `IND`, `THA`, `RUS`, `CHN` and `USA`.
`CHN` and `USA` has skew data.

so if I do `repartition` on `COUNTRY_CODE`, two partitions contains a lot data whereas others are fine. I checked this using `glom()` method.

```
newdf = datadf.repartition("COUNTRY_CODE")

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import  HiveContext, DataFrameWriter, DataFrame

newDF = datadf.repartitionByRange(3,"COUNTRY_CODE","USA")
```

I was trying repartition my data into 3 more partitions for country `USA` and `CHN` only and would like to keep the other countries data into single partition.

```
This is what I am expecting 
AUS- one partition
IND- one partition
THA- one partition
RUS- one partition
CHN- three partition
USA- three partition
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
>   1182, in **getattr**
>       "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, name)) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute
>   'repartitionByRange'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this with hashing:

```
newDf = oldDf.repartition(N, $"col1", $"coln")
```

or for ranging approach:

```
newDF = oldDF.repartitionByRange(N, $"col1", $"coln")
```

There is no custom partitioning for DF's just yet.

In your case I would go for hashing, but there are no guarantees.

But if your data is skew you may need some extra work, like 2 columns for partitioning being the simplest approach.

E.g. an existing or new column - in this case a column that applies a grouping against a given country, e.g. 1 .. N, and the partition on two cols.

For countries with many grouping you get N synthetic sub divisions; for others with low cardinality, only with 1 such group number. Not too hard. Both partitioning can take more than 1 col.

In my view uniform number filling of partitions takes a lot of effort and not really attainable, but a next best approach as in this here can suffice well enough. Amounts to custom partitioning to an extent.

Otherwise, using .withColumn on a DF you can simulate custom partitioning with those rules and filling of a new DF column and then apply the repartitionByRange. Also not so hard.

Comment: How does repartitionByrange function works? Can we use it in Pyspark to repartition the dataframe?

Comment: @Thanks for your help and suggestions. Could you please elaborate more on this last statement. (Otherwise, using .withColumn on a DF you can simulate custom partitioning with those rules and filling of a new DF column and then apply the repartitionByRange. Also not so hard.)

Comment: Partitioning & re-partitioning are big topics - not always well understood. Hashing can lead to skewness more easily, ranges less so. It depends on nature of data. Do you need all data in same partition or can live with stuff in different partitions? But if you want more balanced partititions in terms of numbers - even though there may be disbenefit - then using multiple cols can help awa use of range partitioning. A good article: https://www.24tutorials.com/spark/deep-dive-into-partitioning-in-spark/  However, what I described I have done here and on other systems in the past. Success.

Comment: @thebluephatntom. So we can only use custom partitioning while reading data through external sources or an RDD. Right ?

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: @thebluephantom- Thanks for ur support once again. Ok. Lets say i have a csv file data with header as: id,address,department,country and it has millions of records respectively. For countries like IND,RUS,THA,JPN the data is not much skew. For countries USA and CHN there is a skew data. I want to repartition this data in such a way that smaller countries data resides in each single partition and for USA and CHN , the data gets splitted and divided into further 6 partitions. So i want to have my data repartition into 10 partitions. 4 fr smaller countries and 3 for USA and 3 for CHN..

Comment: With rdd you write own partitioner. with df you simulate in some way. Latter not 100% perfect.

Comment: @thebluephantom- I was not able to find any function name as 'repartitionByRange' for dataframe in Pyspark. It gives me below error. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'repartitionByRange'

Comment: No issue with 2.3.2 Spark. Just looked again. You may need relevant imports. Show the code you are running.

Comment: newdf=datadf.repartitionByRange(10,'model').. datadf has model column and I was using this as a repartitionByRange. I am using spark 2.3 version.

Comment: newDF2cols2 = df.repartitionByRange(3, "c2", "val1") in pyspark works fine for me for 2.3.2. I think you need to check your imports??? Get newDF2cols2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
c1:string
c2:string
val1:long
val2:long

Comment: I was not able to find this method for dataframe. Could you please tell me which class this method resides? Or is there any important classes which i need to import. I am trying to use this method in pyspark spark session 2.3.

Comment: Which version are You ysing?

Comment: I will look tomorrow using spark shell

Comment: Spark 2.3 feature, not 2.2

Comment: I am also using same version 2.3.. am i missing some important import?  I was not able to figure out what i am missing here

Comment: I tried it under 2.2 Databricks and 2.2 spark-shell -> no joy. With data bricks 2.3 it was fine. Interesting, I will have a little further look.

Comment: I cannot check as I only have 2.2 on spark-shell. databricks 2.3 works no issue. Exit for me. Pretty odd, wondering if it is a Databricks extension.

Answer (score 8):

There is no custom partitioner in Structured API, so in order to use custom partitioner, you'll need to drop down to RDD API. Simple 3 steps as follows:

1. Convert Structured API to RDD API

```
dataRDD = dataDF.rdd
```

2. Apply custom partitioner in RDD API

```
import random

# Extract key from Row object
dataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda r: (r[0], r))

def partitioner(key):
    if key == "CHN":
        return random.randint(1, 10)
    elif key == "USA":
        return random.randint(11, 20)
    else:
        # distinctCountryDict is a dict mapping distinct countries to distinct integers
        # these distinct integers should not overlap with range(1, 20)
        return distinctCountryDict[key]

numPartitions = 100
dataRDD = dataRDD.partitionBy(numPartitions, partitioner)

# Remove key extracted previously
dataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda r: r[1])
```

3. Convert RDD API back to Structured API

```
dataDF = dataRDD.toDF()
```

This way, you get the best of both worlds, Spark types and optimized physical plan in Structured API, as well as custom partitioner in low-level RDD API. And we only drop down to low-level API only when it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: I think when we use partitionBy with rdd then key should be of int type.. otherwise it throws an error.. what you say?

Comment: @vikrantrana I'm not having this problem, could you post your error?

Comment: @ythdelmar- Thanks. I was performing similar thing on some rdd and found this thing.. I will check once again if it works with string datatype also. Please see link below for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116294/custom-partitioner-in-pyspark-2-1-0?rq=1

Comment: @vikrantrana The thread also mentioned a potential problem, that you need to have a key-value pair RDD first in order to perform partitionBy, which is this line of my code from above `dataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda r: (r[0], r))`. Perhaps you're getting your error from not having a key-value pair RDD?

Comment: @ythdelmar Does rdd.toDF() preserve partitioning ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to apply user defined partitioner on PySpark, the short cut is to create a new column with a UDF, assigning each record with a partition ID based on the business logic. And use the new column for partitioning, that way the data gets spread evenly.

```
numPartitions= 3
df = df.withColumn("Hash#", udf_country_hash(df['Country']))
df = df.withColumn("Partition#", df["Hash#"] % numPartitions)
df.repartition(numPartitions, "Partition#")
```

Please check the online version of code @
https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8963851468310921/2231943684776180/5846184720595634/latest.html

In my experience converting DataFrame to RDD and back to DataFrame is a costly operation, better to avoid it.

Comment: This will create required partitions, yes. But it is not necessary that each partition is processed in a separate task.. you will notice this when you have a large# of partitions